# Verify a sequence of messages are sent to different objects/classes

Tags: ruby, rspec3

I have an object that saves a model and runs a background job.

```
Class UseCase
  ... 
  def self.perform
    @account.save
    BackgroundJob.perform_later(@account.id)
  end
end
```

In my spec I'd like to test separately that both messages are sent.

I started with something like

```
it 'saves the account' do
  expect_any_instance_of(Account).to receive(:save)
  UseCase.perform(account)
end
```

And this worked fine when I was just saving the account in the `perform`.
But when I have added the background job the spec doesn't pass anymore since now `Couldn't find Account without an ID`.

How can I verify (in RSped 3.5) separately that both messages are sent?

UPDATE

```
it 'runs the job' do
expect(BackgroundJob).to receive(:perform_later).with(instance_of(Fixnum))
UseCase.perform(account)
end
```

passes so I suppose the account is correctly saved.

However, when I try to inspect @account

```
def self.perform
 @account.save
 byebug
 BackgroundJob.perform_later(@account.id)
end
```

In 'saves the account', I get

```
(byebug) @account
#<Account id: nil, full_name: "john doe" ...>
```

In 'runs the job', I get

```
(byebug) @account
#<Account id: 1, full_name: "john doe" ...>
```

The expectation makes `@account` a [test double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/expecting-messages) so in the first spec the job cannot get the id.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a spec that verifies that `@account.save` actually returns `true`? I guess `@account.save` returns `false` aka the account is invalid, wasn't saved and therefore doesn't have an `id` assigned.

Comment: I belive @spickermann is correct. I've added an answer to explain the difference between `save!` and `save`. Hopefully this helps you out

Answer (score 0):

The error `Couldn't find Account without an ID` is actually pretty helpful considering the code that you have inside your `perform` method.

The issue is mentioned in the comments but I'll elaborate a bit further.

You are using `@account.save` (I'm assuming `@account` is an `ActiveRecord` object) which by definition will return `true`/`false` when run ([see documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/save))

What you probably want is to use [`save!`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/save!) instead since it will raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` error and stop execution rather than triggering the error you noted earlier. (toss a `binding.pry` into the method and note what `@account` is when attempting to call `.id`)

When you change to `save!` you can add a test for a case where save might fail (missing attribute, etc). Might look something like this

```
it 'should raise error when trying to save invalid record' do
  # do something to invalidate @account
  @account.username = nil
  expect { UseCase.perform(@account) }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
  #confirm that no messages were sent
end
```

Hope this helps you out! GL and let me know if you have any questions / need more help with rspec

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually don't understand if you are suggesting that my account is not saved or it is saved but `save` does not return what I wish.

Comment: please read the documentation I linked. If `save` returns false then your record did not get saved to the DB (hence the lack of id)